# Error downloading jade using npm (npm install -g jade)

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, npm, pug

I'm trying to download jade via npm on my Mac(Yosemite) but I am getting some errors I can't figure out. I downloaded node and then updated npm after. Then I attempted to install jade and I got the following errors. I also tried to install with sudo but nothing happens. Just some code comes up. I just need help installing jade with npm.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ Dilawer$ node -v
v0.12.5
MacBook-Pro:~ Dilawer$ npm -v
2.12.1
MacBook-Pro:~ Dilawer$ npm install -g jade
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/Dilawer/.npm/jade/1.11.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "jade"
npm ERR! node v0.12.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Dilawer/npm-debug.log
MacBook-Pro:~ Dilawer$ sudo npm install -g jade
Password:
/usr/local/bin/jade -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js
jade@1.11.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade
├── character-parser@1.2.1
├── void-elements@2.0.1
├── commander@2.6.0
├── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── jstransformer@0.0.2 (is-promise@2.0.0, promise@6.1.0)
├── with@4.0.3 (acorn-globals@1.0.4, acorn@1.2.2)
├── constantinople@3.0.1 (acorn-globals@1.0.4)
├── clean-css@3.3.5 (commander@2.8.1, source-map@0.4.2)
├── uglify-js@2.4.23 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, source-map@0.1.34, yargs@3.5.4)
└── transformers@2.1.0 (promise@2.0.0, css@1.0.8, uglify-js@2.2.5)
MacBook-Pro:~ Dilawer$ sudo -s
bash-3.2# npm install -g jade
/usr/local/bin/jade -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js
jade@1.11.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade
├── character-parser@1.2.1
├── void-elements@2.0.1
├── commander@2.6.0
├── mkdirp@0.5.1 (minimist@0.0.8)
├── jstransformer@0.0.2 (is-promise@2.0.0, promise@6.1.0)
├── with@4.0.3 (acorn-globals@1.0.4, acorn@1.2.2)
├── constantinople@3.0.1 (acorn-globals@1.0.4)
├── uglify-js@2.4.23 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, yargs@3.5.4, source-map@0.1.34)
├── clean-css@3.3.5 (commander@2.8.1, source-map@0.4.2)
└── transformers@2.1.0 (promise@2.0.0, css@1.0.8, uglify-js@2.2.5)
bash-3.2#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd install via sudo seams to have installed jade.
Its linking /usr/local/bin/jade to js file /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade/bin/jade.js

type `jade --version` to see if its working.

Comment: Upon entering the directly and running the version command it does give me the proper version. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

According to the log you've provided

> Please try running this command again as root/Administrator

**execute:**

```
sudo npm install -g jade
```

Comment: yep you are right. didn't noticed. **this output looks ok** - it installed successfully in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jade`. have you tried after your last attempt?

Comment: I thank you for your help, when in the jade folder typing jade -h shows the appropriate commands, so i'm certain its installed successfully. Thank you!